# How to create a new log file every time the application runs using logger.config?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging, django-logging

how i can create new info.log file each time app runs. Let me know the cahnges i need to make in this config. I know we have to use doRollover or rotate but how to implement in this config not getting any idea.  Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

file-1. <<log.py >>

```
import configparser
import logging.config

code_dir_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logging_conf = \
    {u'disable_existing_loggers': False,
     u'formatters': {u'basic': {
         u'format': u'%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(threadName)s : %(levelname)s : %(module)s : %(lineno)d : %(message)s'}},
     u'handlers': {u'console': {u'class': u'logging.StreamHandler',
                                u'formatter': u'basic',
                                u'level': u'DEBUG',
                                u'stream': u'ext://sys.stdout'},
                   u'info_file_handler': {u'backupCount': 20,
                                          u'class': u'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
                                          u'encoding': u'utf8',
                                          u'filename': u'info.log',
                                          u'formatter': u'basic',
                                          u'level': u'INFO',
                                          u'maxBytes': 10485760}},
     u'loggers': {u'APP_LOG': {u'handlers': [u'console'],
                               u'level': u'INFO',
                               u'propagate': u'no'}},
     u'root': {u'handlers': [u'console', u'info_file_handler'], u'level': u'INFO'},
     u'version': 1}


def setup_logging(json_filename='logging_conf.json', default_level=logging.INFO,
                  env_key='LOG_CFG', log_file_basepath=".", customised_file_name=""):
    """
      Setup logging configuration
    """
    json_filepath = os.path.join(log_file_basepath, json_filename)
    env_json_filepath = os.getenv(env_key, None)
    if env_json_filepath:
        json_filepath = env_json_filepath
    if logging_conf:
        log_file_name = logging_conf["handlers"]["info_file_handler"]["filename"]
        if customised_file_name:
            log_file_name = customised_file_name
        logging_conf["handlers"]["info_file_handler"]["filename"] = os.path.join(log_file_basepath, log_file_name)
        logging.config.dictConfig(logging_conf)
    else:
        logging.basicConfig(level=default_level)
```

file-2. <<runner.py>>

```
import logging
module_logger = logging.getLogger('JIRA.fetch_data')
setup_logging()
module_logger.info("**Start capturing logs using logging.config")
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't put `'module_logger.doRollover()` after the call to `setup_logging()`?

Comment: @RootTwo
Getting this Error -
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runner.py", line 438, in <module>
    module_logger.doRollover()
AttributeError: 'Logger' object has no attribute 'doRollover'`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do this. The first is to subclass `logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler` and use the subclass:

file 1: <log.py>

```
class CustomRotatingFileHandler(logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler):
    """Rollover when logging gets configured."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print('rollover')
        self.doRollover()
        

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'handlers': {
        'logfile': {
            '()': CustomRotatingFileHandler,  # <<< not in quotes
            'filename': 'test.log',
            'backupCount': 3,
        }
    },
    'root': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'handlers': ['logfile']
    },
}

logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
```

The `'()'` key tells the logging configuration code that you are using custom code to create the handler. If the value is a callable (e.g., a class constructor), it is called with the rest of the dict items (`'filename'` and `'backupcount'`) passed as keyword arguments.

A second way to do it is to use a function instead of a subclass:

```
def force_rollover(wrapped_class):
    def rollover(*args, **kwargs):
        instance =  wrapped_class(*args, **kwargs)
        instance.doRollover()
        return instance
    return rollover

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'handlers': {
        'logfile': {
            '()': force_rollover(logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler),
            'filename': 'info_log',
            'backupCount': 3}
    },
    'root': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'handlers': ['logfile']
    },
}

logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
```

The function `force_rollover()` takes a subclass of `BaseRotatingHandler` and returns a new function. The `'()'` key in the config dict causes the new function to be called, which creates an instance of the subclass, calls its `doRollover()` method, and then returns the instance. The returned instance is then used as the handler.

A third approach would be to get the root logger and use the `getChild()` method to recursively search all the loggers and check their `handlers` attribute to find the handler you want to rollover. This seems like more work than the first two approaches, so I won't go into it.